# Rails include with multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Please anyone help me:

Using Rails I developed an application.

My **models** look like this:

```
    class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :song
      belongs_to :user
    end

    class Song  < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :gsong
      has_many :scores
    end

    class Gsong < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :song
    end

    class user < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :scores
    end
```

And my `ScoresController`:

```
    class scoresController < ApplicationController

     def index
  id = current_user.id
  @scores = score.where(:user_id => id)
      render :json => {
              :scores => @scores.as_json(:include => {:gsong => { :include => { :song => { :only => [:title, :album]}}, :only => [:artwork]}}, :only => [:song_id, :score]),
}
end
```

It's working fine functionally, But it's making too many queries in the database like below:

```
      score Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `scores`.* FROM `scores` WHERE `scores`.`user_id` = 3
      Gsong Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `gsongs`.* FROM `gsongs` WHERE `gsongs`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
      Song Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `songs`.* FROM `songs` WHERE `songs`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
      Gsong Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `gsongs`.* FROM `gsongs` WHERE `gsongs`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
      Song Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `songs`.* FROM `songs` WHERE `songs`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
      Gsong Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `gsongs`.* FROM `gsongs` WHERE `gsongs`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
      Song Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `songs`.* FROM `songs` WHERE `songs`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
      Gsong Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `gsongs`.* FROM `gsongs` WHERE `gsongs`.`id` = 11 LIMIT 1
      Song Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `songs`.* FROM `songs` WHERE `songs`.`id` = 11 LIMIT 1
      Gsong Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `gsongs`.* FROM `gsongs` WHERE `gsongs`.`id` = 12 LIMIT 1
      Song Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `songs`.* FROM `songs` WHERE `songs`.`id` = 12 LIMIT 1
      Gsong Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `gsongs`.* FROM `gsongs` WHERE `gsongs`.`id` = 23 LIMIT 1
      Song Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `songs`.* FROM `songs` WHERE `songs`.`id` = 23 LIMIT 1
```

How can I fetch all this data with single or two queries like:

```
      Gsong Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `gsongs`.* FROM `gsongs` 

     Song Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `songs`.* FROM `songs` WHERE `songs`.`id` IN (8,2,1,11,12,23)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using ActiveModel serializers. I think you'll find it will make complex JSON like this a breeze

There's a great Screencast on it at

http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers